# Search Refiner & refinable strings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've gotten the refinablestrings to appear in the Refinment webpart (as shown below) however the anems are "refinablestring00" etc. How do I change this to a custom name (I was hoping it'd be set to the alias)?

[image]

In the above screenshot the values I'd like to change are "RefinableString00" & "RefinableString02"

Thanks.

Answer:
I didn't set the "displayName" property in the "refinable" search webpart. This is a setting in the webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **displayName** property in the **refinable** search webpart on page.

Edit: Now i see that you found it ;)